# Matlab cell array to string vector - unique

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, unique, cell

Going nuts with cell array, because I just can't get rid of it... However, it will be an easy one for you guys out here.

So here is why:
I have a dataset (data) which contains two variables: A (Numbers) and B (cell array).
Unfortunately I can't even reconstruct the problem nevertheless my imported table looks like this:

```
data=dataset;
data.A = [1;1;3;3;3];
data.B = ['A';'A';'BUU';'BUU';'A'];
```

where data.B is of the type 5x1 cell which I can't reconstruct

all I want now is the unique rows like

ans= [1 A;3 BUU;3 A]
the result should be in a dataset or just two vectors where the rows are equivalent.

but unique([dataA dataB],'rows') can't handle cell arrays and I can't find anywhere in the www how I simple convert the cell array B to a vector of strings (does it exist?).

cell2mat() didn't work for me, because of the different word length ('A' vs 'BUU').

Though, two things I would love to learn: Making an 5x1 cell to an string vector
and find unique rows out of numbers and strings (or cells).

Thank you very much!

Cheers Dominik

Comment: You say `data.B` is a 5x1 cell array, So the line that defines `data.B` should have `{}` instead of `[]`,  right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `A` and `B` fields are of a different type. Although they could be concatenated into a cell array, `unique` can't handle that. A general trick for cases like this is to "translate" elements of each field (column) to unique identifiers, i.e. numbers. This translation can be done applying `unique` to each field separately and getting its third output. The obtained identifiers can now be concatenated into a matrix, so that each row of this matrix is a "composite identifier". Finally, `unique` with `'rows'` option can be applied to this matrix.

So, in your case:

```
[~, ~, kA] = unique(data.A);
[~, ~, kB] = unique(data.B);
[~, jR] = unique([kA kB], 'rows');
```

Now build the result as (same format as `data`)

```
result.A = data.A(jR);
result.B = data.B(jR);
```

or as (2D cell array)

```
result = cat(2, mat2cell(data.A(jR), ones(1,numel(jR))), data.B(jR));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my clumpsy solution

```
    tt.A = [1;1;3;3;3];
    tt.B = {'A';'A';'BUU';'BUU';'A'};
```

Convert integers to characters, then merge and find unique strings

```
   tt.C = cellstr(num2str(tt.A));
   tt.D = cellfun(@(x,y) [x y],tt.C,tt.B,'UniformOutput',0);
   [tt.F,tt.E] = unique(tt.D);
```

Display results

```
   tt.F
```